# Is there a standard-function which prints out/monitor the content of the stdin file while leaving the data inside stdin?

Tags: c++, c, io, stdout, stdin

Is there a faster alternative given with the Standard-Libraries to just read everything/ any character of the `stdin` file, write all characters into an array, thereafter giving the whole arrays content to `stdout` and back (because for its merely "analyzing" purpose) to `stdin` in separate steps?

I just want to analyze, what actually is inside of the `stdin` file, not getting its data out of it, in a easy way.

I can´t find any function of the standard-libraries, which does that.

---

I know this is few, but I think there is nothing more to say about what i want.

Question is for C and C++, as i work with both. If the answers between those alter, please mention which language is in focus.

Comment: `int ch; for (;;) { ch = getchar(); if (ch == EOF) break; putchar(ch); }`

Comment: In my previous comment, between the `break` and the `putchar()` add `/* analyse ch */`

Comment: What does “I just want to analyze, what actually is inside of the `stdin` file.” mean? Does that mean you want the program to analyze the contents of the stream? Or does that mean you just want the program to copy standard input to standard because **you**, literally, are going to look at the standard output and analyze it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just to analyze the containing characters of `stdin`. I don´t know if there is a different way to output the containing characters to the terminal instead of using `stdout` stream.

Comment: C has facilities for reading characters one at a time and for reading many characters at a time. C has facilities for writing one character at a time and for writing many characters at a time. A program can examine and work with those characters one at a time, or it can store them in an array and work on them in arbitrary ways. Whatever you want appears to be completely possible in C. However, it is not at all clear what you want. There does not appear to be any impediment to reading, writing, storing, or analyze in whatever way is desired, so what is stopping you?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know that there are expressions to achieve the output of the current state of the `stdin` and i could implement such separated. I mean, i could write a function in which i incorporate such sequence of expressions, which i will do to come along with this case. The question is as simply as that to ask if there is an in-built function that prints out the characters stored in `stdin` stream. Something like `printfunction(stdin,stdout)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getchar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) to read char by char form `stdin`. However, using a buffer (e.g. an array of chars) will be faster in a lot of scenarios.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    int ch;
    while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF)   /* read/print "abcde" from stdin */
          printf("%c", ch);

    /* Test reason for reaching EOF. */
    if (feof(stdin))          /* if failure caused by end-of-file condition */
       puts("End of file reached");
    else if (ferror(stdin))   /* if failure caused by some other error      */
         {
            perror("getchar()");
            fprintf(stderr,"getchar() failed in file %s at line # %d\n", __FILE__,__LINE__-9);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```